# Running a simple js file on local meteor server

Tags: meteor

Currently when we want to clear data, for example when the data structure changes, we currently uncomment a call to the following function on start up.

```
let clearAllUserResponses = function() {
  if (!Meteor.isDevelopment) {
    console.warn("Won't perform action. Only in Development.");
    return;
  }

  console.log("removing all contract instances");
  let removeCountUI = UserInputs.remove({});
  let removeCountCI = ContractInstances.remove({});
  console.log(
    `removed ${removeCountCI} instances with ${removeCountUI} associated UserInputs`
  );
};
```

However this feels like a task that we could be running from the command line for example something along the lines of `npm run clear-all-user-responses`.

How do I go about defining a function and running a simple function on my local server?

Comment: You can use `meteor shell` and from there call methods.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jankapunkt said, `meteor shell` is probably the way forward.

Another alternative is to use an environment variable...

```
let clearAllUserResponses = function() {

    if (Meteor.isServer && process.env.CLEAN && process.env.CLEAN === "true") {

      if (!Meteor.isDevelopment) {
        console.warn("Won't perform action. Only in Development.");
        return;
      }

     console.log("removing all contract instances");
     let removeCountUI = UserInputs.remove({});
     let removeCountCI = ContractInstances.remove({});
     console.log(
        `removed ${removeCountCI} instances with ${removeCountUI} associated 
         UserInputs`

     );
   }
};
```

Then from the command line...

`CLEAN=true meteor`